# How to get for different pages get fan_count?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

```
GET▾→ /v2.7▾/pepsi?fields=fan_count
```

I am new to graph API, I am interested in getting the facebook fan counts for different pages. 
Using Facebook Graph API explorer, the above code gives me for only 1 page, 
but if I want to get the fan counts for different pages - What should be the code ?
For example- I tried `GET▾→ /v2.7▾/coke,pepsi?fields=fan_count`
but got the error --

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: coke,pepsi",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "FqAQ297ssFe"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#multiidlookup

> You can make a single GET request that retrieves multiple nodes by using the ?ids endpoint with the object IDs of those nodes.

So the request you want to make is: [`?ids=coke,pepsi&fields=fan_count`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3Dcoke%2Cpepsi%26fields%3Dfan_count&version=v2.7)

---

You can retrieve data for up to 50 objects in one go this way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you believe this would be possible, but you need to do two API calls for two Pages. You can only make the API calls faster with **batch requests**, check out the docs for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

They still count as separate API calls though, but it will be as fast as the slowest API call in the batch.